# Using oop in R, unable to understand the concept

Tags: r, matlab, oop

Its my first try to using OOP in R and it's difficult for me to understand the main concept. For example, what are these:

```
slot, setGeneric, representation
```

I was unable to find anything helpful by searching the internet. How do these work in R? For example, I have the following MATLAB class:

```
classdef windTurbine < handle
properties
    NumOfBlades  
    blade@blade 
    sweptArea
end

methods
    function obj = windTurbine(NumOfBlades,blade)
        obj.NumOfBlades = NumOfBlades;
        obj.blade = blade;
        obj.sweptArea = CalcSweptArea(obj);
    end

    sweptArea = CalcSweptArea(obj)
end
```

How do I write this in R? How do I add calculations to the constructor? Make functions private? And mainly use the consept of OOP in R. An example would be helpfull, or a nice tutorial explanation

Comment: Did you read this: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html, which presents R objects as in base and recommended packages, you have also **R6**, which is much closer to what you are doing in Matlab. Your example translates like this:

```
# Need to install R6 first:
# install.packages("R6")
library(R6)

windTurbine <- R6Class("windTurbine",
  public = list(
    # Properties (fields)
    NumOfBlades = integer(0),
    blade = NULL, # Which kind of object is it?
    sweptArea = numeric(0),

    # Methods
    initialize = function(NumOfBlades, blade) {
      self$NumOfBlades <- as.integer(NumOfBlades)
      self$blade <- blade
      self$sweptArea <- self$CalcSweptArea()
    },

    CalcSweptArea = function() {
      # < your code here>
      # (Return a fake value, just for testing)
      return(10)
    }
  ))

wt <- windTurbine$new(NumOfBlades = 6, blade = 3)
wt$sweptArea
```

Look at `?R6Class()`. You have also a `private =` argument for private fields or methods.

Comment: I started using `RefClass` but it seems that `R6` meet my needs better. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: btw because you mentioned also in your comments: how to state that `blade` is a type of another class,for ex.`Blade`?

Comment: You can test it this way: `if (inherits(blade, "Blade")) <do_something> else stop("blade must be a 'Blade' object")`